# VBA Cut & Copy caractères

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I expect to cut/copy my first line into the second of the same sheet.

In my first columne (A1), I have something like :

Spain_1212_Barcelona

Spain_2321_Madrid

....

Is there a smart way for building my second columne that contains only the Spain_XXXX without the city name ? I want to copy only the 7 first caracters. 
Thank you for you time.
Regards

Comment: if it's a constant number of characters you can use `Left` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `InStrRev` to get the position of the last underscore in the string.

```
Function getCountryArea(Text As String)
    getCountryArea = Left(Text, InStrRev(Text, "_") - 1)
End Function
```

[image]

### Update:

```
Function getCountryArea(Text As String)
    Text = Replace(Text, "SP", "Spain")
    getCountryArea = Left(Text, InStrRev(Text, "_") - 1)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function str_name(str_input As String) As String
        
    Dim l_n as long
    
    l_n = InStr(1, str_input, "_", vbTextCompare)
    l_n = InStr(l_n + 1, str_input, "_", vbTextCompare)
    
    str_name = Left(str_input, l_n - 1)
    
End Function

Public Sub TestMe()

    Debug.Print str_name("Spain_1212_Barcelona")
    Debug.Print str_name("Spain_2321_Madrid")

End Sub
```